# How to keep cts:highlight from matching inside XML tags?

Tags: api, rest, search, highlight, marklogic

I am trying to search some content and highlight the search strings present in the XML content(like google) in MarkLogic using REST API. The problem is when I am including "ME" in the search-string,it's highlighting the 'i' tags(html Italic tags) along with the "Me" in the content.  I have created a document with some elements and running a word-query on the document.
For example XML content:

```
         <resources>
         <title> some data from me</title>
         <desc> more data <i> from </i> somewhere by me </desc>
         </resources>
```

I have created a document with root node 'resources' and child elements 'title' and 'desc' and searching the search strings within the document using word-query.

Now when i search for "some me" ,its retrieving the content like

```
         <resources>
         <title> <<span class="highlight">some</span> data from <<span class="highlight">me</span>
          </title>
         <desc> more data <<span class="highlight">i</span>> from <<span class="highlight">i</span>> somewhere by <span class="highlight">me</span>              </desc>
         </resources>
```

Url:

```
localhost:9000/v1/search?q=some me&collection=Data&start=0&pageLength=10&options=Transformation&format=json
```

I am using cts:highlight for highlighting,some thing like :

```
cts:highlight($final-result, $query, fn:concat('<span class="highlight">',$cts:text,'</span>')), $custom-config)
```

Any ideas on why the html elements are highlighted here?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5):

You probably inserted your document in text format, not xml format.  I can reproduce your issue by inserting in text format:

```
xdmp:document-insert("test.xml", text {"<resources>
     <title> some data from me</title>
     <desc> more data <i> from </i> somewhere by me </desc>
     </resources>"})
```

then running a cts:highlight on that document:

```
cts:highlight(doc("test.xml"), cts:parse("some me"), concat('<span class="highlight">', $cts:text, '</span>'))
```

But if I re-insert the document as XML:

```
xdmp:document-insert("test.xml", <resources>
     <title> some data from me</title>
     <desc> more data <i> from </i> somewhere by me </desc>
     </resources>)
```

then the same cts:highlight works better:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <title> &lt;span class="highlight"&gt;some&lt;/span&gt; data from &lt;span class="highlight"&gt;me&lt;/span&gt;</title>
  <desc> more data <i> from </i> somewhere by &lt;span class="highlight"&gt;me&lt;/span&gt; </desc>
</resources>
```

If I add the suggestion from @ehennum and @mholstege and instead run this cts:highlight:

```
cts:highlight(doc("test.xml"), cts:parse("some me"), <span class="highlight">{$cts:text}</span>)
```

then I get what I would guess you're looking for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <title> <span class="highlight">some</span> data from <span class="highlight">me</span></title>
  <desc> more data <i> from </i> somewhere by <span class="highlight">me</span> </desc>
</resources>
```

Comment: For those wondering why "i" is highlighted in addition to "me", that is because "i" is the stem of "me", and the database is probably configured to use stemmed searches by default. You can suppress that by adding the `unstemmed` or `exact` option to the word-query..

Comment: Agreed, the xml tags shouldn't be searched unless they are considered plain text.  Well put.

Answer (score 1):

What version of MarkLogic is this?

Can you include a more complete example? What is $custom-config for example? And how is the REST call results linked to cts:highlight? For markup to be highlighted in this way, that results would have to be text rather than XML.

By the way, the third argument to cts:highlight is an expression -- if you want to create markup, just use constructors there, not string concatenation:

```
cts:highlight($final-result, $query, <span class="highlight">{$cts:text}</span>, $custom-config)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try supplying the tags in the cts:hightlight() expression as nodes instead of a string.

That is, instead of

```
fn:concat('<span class="highlight">',$cts:text,'</span>')
```

try

```
<span class="highlight">{$cts:text}</span>
```

For more information, see the first example in:

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:highlight?q=cts:highlight

Hoping that helps,